# Changing (Forcing) Screen Resolution on OUYA

Tags: ouya

OUYA doesn't provide any built-in (UI-based) way to change or force a resolution. This is a problem for some (like me) who have no HDMI devices, and use HDMI to DVI adapters, or simply have devices which do not correctly display the best resolution. (For clarity, OUYA defaults to 640x480 if it can't display a higher resolution).

To clarify, I'm using a 20-something inch "normal" monitor (no HDMI input), so I see very pixelated writing that's hard to read in the OUYA menu. Some games, like Final Fantasy, appear to display decently though.

[This XDA Developers thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2294465) found two methods that works for some OUYA users. It's not clear if these actually change the resolution though.

**Method 1:**

1. `cat modes` displays all the possible display modes. (`cat mode` displays the current mode.)
2. `echo 0 > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/device/enable`
3. `echo (videomodefrommodesfile) > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode`
4. `echo 1 > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/device/enable`

**Method 2:** Run `am display-size (resolution)`. For example, `am display-size 1080x720` should change the (virtual?) display size to 1080x720 px. But other users in the same thread report that this causes other display issues, like shrinking the display.

Is there a consistent way to change the display resolution?